# Find number of distinct elements in a linked list

Tags: java

I have a LinkedList that contains many objects. How can I find the number and frequency of the distinct elements in the LinkedList.

Comment: iterate through the list and count objects by their hash?

Comment: How do you want to report the result? i.e. is System.out.println(node, frequency) acceptable?

Comment: @kasavbere Yeah that would be acceptable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate the list with a [for-each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) while maintaining a [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram).

The histogram will actually be a [`Map<T,Integer>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) where `T` is the type of the elements in the linked list.

If you use a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), this will get you `O(n)` average case algorithm for it - be sure you override [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) for your `T` elements. [if `T` is a built-in class [like `Integer` or `String`], you shouldn't be worried about this, they already override these methods].

The idea is simple: iterate the array, for each element: search for it in the histogram - if it is not there, insert it with value 1 [since you just saw it for the first time]. If it is in the histogram already, extract the `value`, and re-insert the element - with the same key and with `value + 1`.

should look something like this: [`list` is of type `LinkedList<Integer>`]

```
Map<Integer,Integer> histogram = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
for (Integer x : list) {
    Integer value = histogram.get(x);
    if (value == null) histogram.put(x,1);
    else histogram.put(x, value + 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. How do I iterate a list to a histogram? If you could point me to some documentation I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @rmp2150: Iterate the list using for-each loop. I added documentation for it in my answer [first line]. I also added a code snap how to build the histogram.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm still fairly new to Java and I've never used hashmaps before. Thanks for thoroughly explaining the process.

Comment: @rmp2150: You are most welcome. I'd recommend you to read the links I provided - and get familiar with [java.util](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html) package - there are some very useful things thers, that you will surely need to use many times.

Comment: I definitely will check out the documentation. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

A simpler variation of the histogram solution with a [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) [`Multiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release12/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html):

```
Multiset<Integer> multiset = HashMultiset.create();
multiset.addAll(linkedList);

int count = multiset.count(element); // number of occurrences of element
Set<Integer> distinctElements = multiset.elementSet();
  // set of all the unique elements seen
```

(Disclosure: I work on Guava.)

Answer (score 1):

@amit's answer is good, but I want to share a slight variation (and can't format a block of code in comment - otherwise this would just be a comment).  I like to make two passes, one to create the histogram elements and the second to populate them.  This feels cleaner to me, although it may be less efficient.

```
Map<Integer,Integer> histogram = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
for (Integer n : list)
    histogram.put(n, 0);
for (Integer n : list)
    histogram.put(n, histogram.get(n) + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [LambdaJ Library](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) offers a few interesting methods to query collections very easily as well:

```
List<Jedi> jedis = asList(
        new Jedi("Luke"),  new Jedi("Obi-wan"), new Jedi("Luke"), 
        new Jedi("Yoda"), new Jedi("Mace-Windu"),new Jedi("Luke"), 
        new Jedi("Obi-wan")
        );

Group<Jedi> byName = with(jedis).group(Groups.by(on(Jedi.class).getName()));
System.out.println(byName.find("Luke").size()); //output 3
System.out.println(byName.find("Obi-wan").size()); //ouput 2
```

Answer (score 0):

i have just learned about HashSet. i have no idea about map yet. so let me suggest my solution base on HashSet.

```
for(String a:Linklist1){
              if(Hashset1.add(a){
                                 count++;
                                }
                       }
System.out.println(count);
```

hope this helps.